# How to protect single domain webapp from XSS with Content Security Policy?

Tags: security, xss

I have a web application that I want to protect against XSS. In particular, there are no:

- form submissions to other domains
- JS files from other domains
- links pointing to other domains
- iframes, embeds, objects

There is however (unfortunately) lots of inline JS which I will be moving to JS files so I can remove `unsafe-inline` from CSP.

The way I see it, the Content Security Policy should look like this:

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
child-src 'none'; 
frame-src 'none'; 
object-src 'none'; 
base-uri 'self'; 
form-action 'self'; 
frame-ancestors 'none'; 
plugin-types 'none'; 
report-uri 'self'; 
sandbox '';
```

1. Did I miss anything?
2. Is there some easier way to mitigate `unsafe-inline` risk than moving all inline JS to external files?

Comment: apart from these, don't forget to escape every possible type of input. For a comprehensive discussion let me point you to [OWASP cheat sheet].(https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @MaVVamaldo: of course - but that is a whole other layer of protection. What I am looking for is some additional mitigation in case of programming mistakes. Any idea if the above configuration makes sense?

Comment: If your webpage include user-generated content (like username for example) you SHOULD move all inline JS to external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have inline code if you really want.

See the "If You Absolutely Must Use It…" section [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

Basically you either use the `nonce` attribute on the `script` tag

```html
<script nonce=EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa>
  //Some inline code I cant remove yet, but need to asap.
</script>
```

and then reference this nonce in the CSP:

```http
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa'
```

or you generate a SHA hash of the script content and then reference this in the CSP:

```http
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG-HiZ1guq6ZZDob_Tng='
```

Once this is done you'll want to remove the 'unsafe-inline' directive for your CSP to be effective. Note that you can only do `<script>` blocks in this way and not attributes that support script (e.g. `OnMouseOver`). You can however assign events such as these using external JavaScript or `<script>` blocks that you have allowed as above.

Remember that any nonce's should be generated on-the-fly using a CSPRNG, otherwise any attacker could simply append the static nonce to their injected script tag. You could save the value against the session though, in order to prevent the extra processing in generating it per page load.